Code in one line without using compound expression
data = Range[10]^2
Table[Style[data[[n]], FontSize->data[[n]]], {n, Length[data]}]


I understand that the above can also be coded in one line. But I could do so only in two steps. Is it okay to break this way while approaching similar problems?

Terrible, uninformative title.  Please rewrite it.

First of all, while I understand your question, it's worth pointing out that, no matter how you code, usually there will be many "steps". (Just check the code with Trace! ) A more precise description for your problem is probably "code in one line without using CompoundExpression (;)".
Then, here's one possible solution, which (I believe) fulfills the purpose of the exercise 7.14 in An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language best. As mentioned in Section 6:

Table[f[n], {n, {v1, v2, v3...}}] lets you make a table using whatever values of n you want; here you would get {f[v1], f[v2], f[v3], ...}. In Section 25, we’ll see how to get the same result with Map.

The syntax is also well-documented, of course:


So:
Table[Style[n, FontSize -> n], {n, Range[10]^2}]


this form
x = someExpr
g[x]

could be rewritten into
g[#]&[someExpr]

for your example
Table[Style[#[[n]], FontSize->#[[n]]], {n, Length[#]}] & [ Range[10]^2 ]

this way is called https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion
and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65622/whats-the-point-of-eta-conversion-in-lambda-calculus

but more mathematica-style way, check @xzczd 's answer.

